# Plugin para upload de arquivos grandes no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou desenvolvendo um **blog com wordpress** para um cliente (que tem pouca experiência com computador e internet). Neste blog, serão disponibilizados vídeos e arquivos zips para download.

Pensando que estes arquivos podem **variar bastante de tamanho** (até 350MB) fui procurar um meio de realizar este upload (pelo wp-admin) sem precisar aumentar o max_upload_size no servidor e nem o timeout porque acredito não ser a melhor opção.

Pesquisando em diversos lugares vejo que a maioria das pessoas realiza o **upload via FTP** e utiliza um plugin que pega os arquivos que estão na máquina e coloca no blog, porém acredito que isto seja algo **muito difícil** para alguém sem experiência.

Achei um **único plugin** (http://www.iptanus.com/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-file-upload/) que apenas em sua versão paga faz este upload de maneira satisfatória mas devido a encontrar apenas um plugin e não encontrar muita gente utilizando fiquei com um pé atrás.

Este plugin é confiável? Existem algum outro plugins que faça isso e é mais utilizado? Esta (subir arquivos grandes para disponibilizar no wordpress) é uma abordagem ruim por isso existe pouco a respeito?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É uma situação bastante atípica, então não vai ter muita garantia mesmo.
Eu criaria uma regra para aumentar o `max_upload_size` só na sessão logada do usuário com `ini_set`  no processo de login.

Comment: Não gostaria de fazer apenas isso porque acredito que o feedback pro usuário é ruim. O tempo de espera é muito grande e possívelmente ele vá achar que não deu certo.

Comment: pode colocar um plugin de feedback com barra de status do upload, a sessão vai ficar presa.. mas com 350 Mb de upload não tem muito jeito.. precisa desse feedback.. se não o cliente fecha a janela achando que já fez o upload e depois vai reclamar com você que o arquivo não sobe... experiencia própria...

Comment: @BrenoZan, parece que a sua resposta estava certa...(+1) Dá para editar para ficar mais composta?

Comment: Só pra complementar a resposta: eu tenho um cliente que sobe todo dia imagens e arquivos de 400 a 500mb no WordPress pelo uploader comum, implementado no Front End, sem nenhum problema - com upload múltiplo e a barra de status funcionando normalmente. Tendo um servidor com memória suficiente pra fazer as operações após o upload não é necessário nenhum plugin pra isso, só aumentar o max_upload_size mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a aba de Mídia do seu painel do Wordpress para uploads de arquivos. Para aumentar esse limite você pode alterar o php.ini o campo **max_upload_size** para 350MB. :)